# Mirror worksheet between two workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, replication, mirror

What I am trying to achieve is as follows, I have "Workbook A" and "Workbook B", within Workbook B there is a worksheet "SheetB2" which I would like to be included in Workbook A. However, any changes made to SheetB2 in Workbook A I would like to be replicated to the corresponding worksheet in Workbook B and vice versa.

1. Is this possible within excel utilizing built in tools or VBA?
2. Could people point me in the direction of the tools or VBA scripting that would be required to make this possible? I'd imagine there will be a number of steps to a suitable solution.

Comment: Try the [`Workbook.SheetChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) event; note that both workbooks must be open simultaneously.

Comment: Why make this a two-way street? wouldn't it be better to do the data entry in A and pull data from A into B?

Comment: @jkpieterse, the intention for the workbooks is to allow a form of collaborative working between multiple parties. Workbook A is essential a master workbook controlled by myself, Workbook B will be the responsibility of another party, who will not have access to the master Workbook A. I will be in control of Workbook A and wish to view and edit data in that workbook alone, rather than have to modify multiple different workbooks.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I would avoid Workbook.SheetChange, it might make things messy.  I would add an "update" button in workbook B, so each time the B user is done with updating the worksheet B2, it would press the update button to copy the data from B to A. and you can have a similar button in workbook A to update workbook B

Comment: How do you resolve conflicts when the same cells are changed in both documents?

Comment: @AnchorBobs I thill think you'd best keep the data to be edited in one place. Maybe ensure each workbook to have two tabs. In the file you edit you have your own tab with your data and another one which is connected (get data, from file) to the editable tab of the user. And vice versa. If data needs to be combined, both workbooks can have a query to join these tables into an overview. Set the queries to refresh every x seconds.